# Can I get top 10 group list from MongoDb which is order by members count

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have 2 collections one is for group details and other is for group_members details, 
group_members have group's _id stored (as FK)

Like 
group : -> _id,name,type,date

group_members -> _id,group_id,members_id,role,status

so how can I get the groups that have most count of memebrs in that with order by group_membrs's count (top 10 groups with more members)

Comment: What part are you stuck with? What have you tried? Have you looked up how to "sort" and "limit" queries?  Or is it the join that is the issue?

Comment: I stuck with from where I have to start 
If I got all list and then sort with members length but it's come up with all groups so take some time to execute and not a proper way, so how could I fire query about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the `groupMembers` collection contains the group ID as you describe, e.g.:

```
var r = [
 {_id: "M1", gid: "A", member: "Bob"}
 ,{_id: "M2", gid: "A", member: "Sally"}
 ,{_id: "M3", gid: "A", member: "Dan"}
 ,{_id: "M4", gid: "B", member: "Tess"}
 ,{_id: "M5", gid: "B", member: "George"}
 ,{_id: "M6", gid: "C", member: "P_1"}
 ,{_id: "M7", gid: "C", member: "P_2"}
 ,{_id: "M8", gid: "C", member: "P_3"}
 ,{_id: "M9", gid: "C", member: "P_4"}
 ];
 db.foo2.insert(r);
```

Then this is how you'd get the count in each group:

```
c=db.foo2.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$gid", n: {$sum:1} }}
  ,{$sort: {n: -1}}
  ,{$limit: 10}
]);
```

If we toss in the group master collection, e.g.

```
var r = [
     {_id: "A", name: "GroupA"}
     ,{_id: "B", name: "GroupB"}
     ,{_id: "C", name: "GroupC"}
];
db.foo.insert(r);
```

Then we simply do a `$lookup` to "join" the data:

```
db.foo2.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$gid", n: {$sum:1} }}
  ,{$sort: {n: -1}}
  ,{$limit: 10}
  ,{$lookup: { from: "foo", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "X"}}
]);
```

Which will yield something like this:

```
{
"_id" : "C",
"n" : 4,
"X" : [
    {
        "_id" : "C",
        "name" : "GroupC"
    }
]
}
{
"_id" : "A",
"n" : 3,
"X" : [
    {
        "_id" : "A",
        "name" : "GroupA"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: using this I got the result like this

/* 1 createdAt:24/01/2018, 18:45:30*/

{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a6886f2f78861dd29bec5ad"),
 "n" : 15.0
},

/* 2 createdAt:18/01/2018, 05:57:39*/
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a5fe9fb530b20c853804b04"),
 "n" : 8.0
},
.
.
.

Can i get the details of that group instead of _id only ??

Comment: can I get the details of that group also instead of id's

Comment: @SmitPatel  I expanded the answer above to show the $lookup.